# inner join to 3 tables but dont show anything

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

there are 3 tables like this:

```
mysql> describe detoc;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| registro  | int(12)      | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| ordcomp   | int(12)      | NO   | MUL | 0          |                |
| requis    | int(12)      | YES  | MUL | 0          |                |
| requisnum | int(12)      | YES  |     | 0          |                |
| material  | char(6)      | YES  | MUL |            |                |
| cantidad  | double(18,7) | YES  |     | 0.0000000  |                |
| unidad    | char(7)      | YES  |     |            |                |
| presest   | double(18,7) | YES  |     | 0.0000000  |                |
| unidadpre | char(7)      | YES  |     |            |                |
| surtido   | double(18,7) | YES  |     | 0.0000000  |                |
| cerrada   | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0          |                |
| costo     | double(18,7) | YES  |     | 0.0000000  |                |
| impuesto  | double(18,7) | YES  |     | 0.0000000  |                |
| fechalta  | date         | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
| usuarmod  | char(6)      | YES  |     |            |                |
| fechamod  | date         | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
16 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> describe ordenescompra;
+------------+------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+------------+------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| registro   | int(12)    | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| clave      | int(12)    | NO   | MUL | 0          |                |
| area       | char(6)    | NO   | MUL |            |                |
| usuariocre | char(6)    | NO   | MUL |            |                |
| cveprov    | char(6)    | YES  |     |            |                |
| fechacomp  | char(10)   | YES  |     |            |                |
| emailconf  | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | 0          |                |
| confprov   | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | 0          |                |
| cerrada    | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | 0          |                |
| fechalta   | date       | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
| usuarmod   | char(6)    | YES  |     |            |                |
| fechamod   | date       | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
+------------+------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> describe materiales;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| registro  | int(12)      | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| clave     | char(6)      | NO   | UNI |            |                |
| clave2    | char(20)     | YES  | MUL |            |                |
| descr     | char(30)     | YES  |     |            |                |
| descr2    | char(250)    | YES  |     |            |                |
| unidad    | char(7)      | YES  |     |            |                |
| presest   | double(18,7) | YES  |     | 0.0000000  |                |
| unidadpre | char(7)      | YES  |     |            |                |
| codbar    | char(30)     | YES  |     |            |                |
| impuesto  | double(18,7) | YES  |     | 0.0000000  |                |
| mantpend  | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0          |                |
| grupplat  | char(6)      | YES  | MUL |            |                |
| fechalta  | date         | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
| usuarmod  | char(6)      | YES  |     |            |                |
| fechamod  | date         | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
```

I need to display data , but returns nothing, the syntaxis is:

```
SELECT * FROM DETOC INNER JOIN MATERIALES  
            ON DETOC.MATERIAL = MATERIALES.CLAVE 
        INNER JOIN ORDENESCOMPRA
            ON DETOC.ORDCOMP = ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE  

            WHERE MATERIALES.CLAVE>='      ' 
            AND MATERIALES.CLAVE<='ZZZZZZ' 
            AND MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT>='      ' 
            AND MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT<='ZZZZZZ'
            AND ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE>='            '
            AND ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE<='999999999999'
             ORDER BY ;
```

and i try this syntaxis too, but i have a error to show, because they're different number of columns...

```
(SELECT * FROM DETOC  
  INNER JOIN ORDENESCOMPRA  
  ON DETOC.ORDCOMP = ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE    

  WHERE ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE>="8780" 
    AND ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE<="8790"
    ORDER BY CLAVE)

UNION

  (SELECT * FROM DETOC
   INNER JOIN MATERIALES 
    ON DETOC.MATERIAL = MATERIALES.CLAVE
    WHERE MATERIALES.CLAVE>="" 
    AND MATERIALES.CLAVE<="" 
    AND MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT>="      "
    AND MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT<="      ")
```

Can anybody help me ???

Comment: If you're not getting any results, nothing matches the criteria in the query. Can you post some sample data, and the result you're expecting to get?

Comment: doing < and > on strings is a bit unusual. Without the data I can't tell if that's the problem. Can you run the query without the string comparison where clause?

Comment: To add on to @Barmar 's comment, `INNER JOIN` only returns results when there's a "match" across all 3 tables.

Comment: To add to @mopo922's comment, you might need to use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: in your `WHERE` clause, you're treating `ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE` as a string, but it's defined as an int. In general, your `WHERE` clause looks like you're trying to do something that could be done easier. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Why all the string with multiple spaces.  It is really just unclear what you are trying to do here, since, as was previously stated, you are doing comparisons on strings that seem very unsual.  Are you in essence trying to do regex comparisons (i.e. string should be six characters whch can be [a-zA-Z] and spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Please try using `UPPER` function while comparing `MATERIALES.CLAVE` and `MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT` with their upper bounds, like in the following query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    DETOC 
    INNER JOIN MATERIALES  
               ON DETOC.MATERIAL = MATERIALES.CLAVE 
    INNER JOIN ORDENESCOMPRA
               ON DETOC.ORDCOMP = ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE  
WHERE 
    MATERIALES.CLAVE >= '      ' 
    AND UPPER(MATERIALES.CLAVE) <= 'ZZZZZZ' 
    AND MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT >= '      ' 
    AND UPPER(MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT) <= 'ZZZZZZ'
    AND ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE >= '            '
    AND ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE <= '999999999999';
```

I'm not sure whether this will solve your problem, but I'm certain that when in `MATERIALES.CLAVE` there would be i.e. value `AABBcc` the query would exclude the record from the result set.

Hope it helps some way.